# "Are there lots of people about?"

Tags: grammar

What is the meaning of the sentence & the meaning of **about** in this sentence?

> "Are there lots of people about?"

Comment: The speaker asks if there are many people in the area (probably in the streets, since we wouldn't use 'about' for people assembled in a building for a meeting etc.).

Comment: thanks, I was reading a story book,and the word "about" confused me.